# Is ++ operator more expensive than | operator in Erlang?

Tags: erlang

I was reading [Learn You Some Erlang](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/content) and I came upon this example in the [Recursion](http://learnyousomeerlang.com/recursion#more-recursive-functions) chapter.

```
tail_sublist(_, 0, SubList) -> SubList;
tail_sublist([], _, SubList) -> SubList;
tail_sublist([H|T], N, SubList) when N > 0 -> 
tail_sublist(T, N-1, [H|SubList]).
```

As the author goes on to explain that there is a *fatal flaw* in our code. It being that the sub lists hence produced would be reverse and we would have to re-reverse them to get the correct output. In contrast, what I did was use the `++` operator to avoid reversing the list later.

```
sublist_tail([],_,Acc) -> Acc;
sublist_tail(_,0,Acc) -> Acc;
sublist_tail([H|T],N,Acc) -> sublist_tail(T,N-1,Acc++[H]).
```

My question is, **is the `++` operator more expensive than the `|` operator?** And if it is, **would my solution (using `++` operator) still be slow compared to the author's solution (including reversing the list to get the correct output)?**

Comment: the operator ++ expensive operation, as to obtain the result you need to run through the left argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is the ++ operator more expensive than the | operator?

That depends. If you use it correctly, then no. `++` is only dangerous when you have a big left-hand-side operand.

Each time a "`++`"-operator is invoked on a left-hand List (like: `List1 ++ List2`), you are creating a new List, that is a copy of your left-hand operand (`List1`). Each copy operation then has a runtime, that is dependent on the length of your `List1` (which keeps growing with your iterations).

So, if you prepend your values 'head first', you don't have to perform a copy-operation over the whole list in each step. This also means,  accumulation with `++` at the head of the List wouldn't be so bad either, since only the "H"-value is copied once in each iteration:

```
sublist_tail([H|T],N,Acc) -> sublist_tail(T,N-1,[H]++Acc).
```

But if you are already accumulating head-first (and thus have to reverse later anyhow), you can do it with the cons-operator (`|`)

```
sublist_tail([H|T],N,Acc) -> sublist_tail(T,N-1,[H|Acc]).
```

This is the 'proper' way, since (*please correct me if I am wrong*) `++` is only syntactic sugar and is implemented internally with a cons-operator (`|`).

Answer (score 6):

You might want to read about this issue in the [Erlang efficiency guide](http://www.erlang.org/doc/efficiency_guide/listHandling.html), since there it says that building the list via `|` and then reversing the result is more efficient than using the appending `++` operator. If you want to know the performance difference, use `timer:tc`:

```
1> timer:tc(fun() -> lists:reverse(lists:foldl(fun(V, Acc) -> [V|Acc] end, [], lists:seq(1,1000))) end).
{1627,
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
  23,24,25,26,27|...]}
2> timer:tc(fun() -> lists:foldl(fun(V, Acc) -> Acc++[V] end, [], lists:seq(1,1000)) end).
{6216,
 [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,
  23,24,25,26,27|...]}
```

Both approaches create lists of 1000 integers, but these measurements based on Erlang/OTP 17.5 show the prepending/reversing version is roughly 4x faster than the appending version (YMMV of course).

Comment: It would be worth to note what will happen for 10000 numbers :-)

Comment: ^and for 100000 numbers. :D

Comment: Measuring 100000 integers with the same system shows the time for the prepending/reversing version increases neatly by a factor of 100 over the 1000 integer version, as you'd expect, but the time for the appending version increases by a factor of roughly 4500 from having to continually traverse the list to append to it.