# How can I add values to an already created list?

Tags: erlang

I have been trying to get this done but I cant, I want to achieve something like this:

Example input: [1,2,3,4]

Example output: ["zero", "one", "two","four"]

```
Data_list = Unknown_list_of_numbers,
Final_list = ["zero"],
lists:foreach(
    fun(Number) ->
      case Number of
        1 ->
            Final_list.append("one");
        2 ->
            Final_list.append("two");
        %% Few more case clauses %%
      end
    end,
    Data_list
),
function_to_do_something_with_name_of_numbers(Final_list).
```

Comment: add data for input and expeted output.

Comment: Hi @Atomic_alarm I added them before the code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use `lists:map` for this?

`lists:map` iterates over all elements of the list and applies a function to the elements. It could look like something like this:

```
my_function(Input) ->
    F=fun(X) -> 
        case X of
            1 -> "one";
            2 -> "two";
            3 -> "three";
            % and so on... you get the idea
            _ -> "-"
        end
     end,

     lists:map(F, Input).
```

This would be your core logic. To add the result of it to an existing list, simply append it with the ´++´ operator:

```
Input=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8].
["zero"] ++ my_function(Input).
```

Be careful though, the `++` operator has terrible performance issues when used naiveley (it basically copes all entries of the left-hand list before appending). If you want to use it iterativeley (over and over again to create a list), you are better of to accumulate head-first and then reverse, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30529559/is-operator-more-expensive-than-operator-in-erlang) for clarification...